# execve system call disassembly

Tags: assembly, system-calls

I am trying to understand, how an `execve` system call works and the underlying assembly. Here is my sample program:

```
// p1.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
   char *name[2];
   name[0] = "/bin/sh";
   name[1] = NULL;
   execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

My system is `x86_64`. I compiled it using  `gcc -ggdb -static -fno-stack-protector p1.c`. Gcc version was `7.3.0`

Here is the `objdump -d ./a.out` for `main` only

```
0000000000400b4d <main>:
  400b4d:   55                      push   %rbp
  400b4e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400b51:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400b55:   48 8d 05 08 14 09 00    lea    0x91408(%rip),%rax        # 491f64 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
  400b5c:   48 89 45 f0             mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
  400b60:   48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
  400b67:   00 
  400b68:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  400b6c:   48 8d 4d f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rcx
  400b70:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  400b75:   48 89 ce                mov    %rcx,%rsi
  400b78:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400b7b:   e8 50 7f 04 00          callq  448ad0 <__execve>
  400b80:   90                      nop
  400b81:   c9                      leaveq 
  400b82:   c3                      retq   
  400b83:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400b8a:   00 00 00 
  400b8d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

I understood every line till `callq  448ad0 <__execve>` call. Then I checked the `__execve` assembly from the `objdump` ooutput.

```
0000000000448ad0 <__execve>:
  448ad0:   b8 3b 00 00 00          mov    $0x3b,%eax
  448ad5:   0f 05                   syscall 
  448ad7:   48 3d 01 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
  448add:   73 01                   jae    448ae0 <__execve+0x10>
  448adf:   c3                      retq   
  448ae0:   48 c7 c1 c0 ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffc0,%rcx
  448ae7:   f7 d8                   neg    %eax
  448ae9:   64 89 01                mov    %eax,%fs:(%rcx)
  448aec:   48 83 c8 ff             or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
  448af0:   c3                      retq   
  448af1:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  448af8:   00 00 00 
  448afb:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

I understood that `edx,rsi,rdi` registers are used to pass the `execve` arguments form the `main` function. But I can't find any assembly code to process these arguments inside `__execve` code.

What I guess `$0x3b` may the syscall number and `syscall` instruction hides most of the implementation. If I do interactive gdb forward steps, then after the `syscall instruction` at `448ad5:` shell prompt starts.

Can I get to know(if yes **how** ?), what other registers and are used to process the arguments and execute `__execve` system call ? Or, does the `syscall` instruction at address `448ad5:`  directly takes argument values from `edx,rsi,rdi` registers?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6

Comment: The `syscall` instruction does a system call. The `execve` instruction is just a thin wrapper around that.  All the argument processing and related stuff happens in the kernel.